# How to remove the console from the Roblox Exploit Api Dll Inject

Tags: roblox

I got the api sauce and I'm editing it.
When you inject the api, the console comes out and tells you to enter the command there.
I just want to erase the console that comes out by injecting api, inject and execute what I wrote as a command into the C# text box, but it didn't go well.
So I fixed the code in the console window, a[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjD24.png)nd Roblox crashed.
Tell me how to solve this problem.

And I will show you the status code with the console coming out and the code with the error after fixing it without the console coming out. Make sure the console doesn't come out, and if the command you wrote down in the text box presses the Execute button, let Roblox run it.

Code before modification (state with console)

```
void main()
{
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), 0);
    CONSOLEBYPASS();
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
    HWND ConsoleHandle = GetConsoleWindow();
    SetWindowPos(ConsoleHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 50, 20, 0, 0, SWP_DRAWFRAME | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    ShowWindow(ConsoleHandle, 1);
    SetConsoleTitle("Sxploit // Credits to Aero // Updated by L");
    XHosted::Run(XHosted::GetVersion());
    //XHosted::XDumper();
    RobloxState = XHosted::GetRState();
    VanillaState = luaL_newstate();
    BreakPointsInit();
    luaL_openlibs(VanillaState);
    luaL_newmetatable(VanillaState, "garbagecollector");
    lua_pushcfunction(VanillaState, UserDataGC);
    lua_setfield(VanillaState, -2, "gc");
    lua_pushvalue(VanillaState, -1);
    lua_setfield(VanillaState, -2, "index");
    WrapGlobals(RobloxState, VanillaState);
    SetLevel(RobloxState, 7);
    RegisterShittyFunc(VanillaState);
    lua_newtable(VanillaState);
    lua_setglobal(VanillaState, "_G");
    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)input, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    std::string i;
    Execute("warn('Connect to Roblox')");
    while (true) {
        getline(std::cin, i);
        Execute(i.c_str());
        i = "";
    }
}

BOOL WINAPI CONSOLEBYPASS()
{
    DWORD nOldProtect;
    if (!VirtualProtect(FreeConsole, 1, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &nOldProtect))
        return FALSE;
    (BYTE)(FreeConsole) = 0xC3; //opcode time
    if (!VirtualProtect(FreeConsole, 1, nOldProtect, &nOldProtect))
        return FALSE;
    AllocConsole();
}
```

Code after modification (the console does not come out, but the Inject causes the Roblox to crash)

```
void main()
{
    BreakPointsInit();
    luaL_openlibs(VanillaState);
    luaL_newmetatable(VanillaState, "garbagecollector");
    lua_pushcfunction(VanillaState, UserDataGC);
    lua_setfield(VanillaState, -2, "gc");
    lua_pushvalue(VanillaState, -1);
    lua_setfield(VanillaState, -2, "index");
    WrapGlobals(RobloxState, VanillaState);
    SetLevel(RobloxState, 6);
    RegisterShittyFunc(VanillaState);
    lua_newtable(VanillaState);
    lua_setglobal(VanillaState, "_G");
    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)input, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    std::string i;
    Execute("warn('Connect to Roblox')");
}
```

The picture over there is the console window I want to erase.

Answer (score 1):

You cant remove that console app from here, this console is used to push lua script that given by pipes from your exploit to roblox, the only way how to teke out that console is to hide it.
As i understand this is a c++ code right?

```
void HideConsole()
{
    ::ShowWindow(::GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Axon Source i can see, you can give the code pls?

```
//Necesary for hide console
#include <Windows.h>

    //Hide Console
    void HideConsole()
    {
        ::ShowWindow(::GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
    }
    //Check Is Console Visible
    bool IsConsoleVisible()
    {
        return ::IsWindowVisible(::GetConsoleWindow()) != FALSE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Axon is currently entirely patched, I would suggest checking out Imperious Transpiler with more stability and actually working!

Check it here: https://v3rmillion.net/showthread.php?pid=7615717

(Also if you don't know the basic fix for that, I don't think you will be able to update addys every Wednesday.)